# how to get value of one variable from one js to another js file in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi am having one index file with login.js where value of var imp is set, i need to use this var imp value in another html file where am including another js file where differnt dialogs are populated depending on functions. But am not able to get the value can someone help me please thanks.

in index.jsp i added login.js. in second.html i included both login.js and function.js where in login.js i added a function as

```
function getSolutionURL(){
 return baseURL;
 }
```

where this method is called inside second.html page on document.ready but it is not working

Comment: in index.jsp i added login.js.    in second.html i included both login.js and function.js where in login.js i added a function as function getSolutionURL(){
         return baseURL;
 }  
where this method is called inside second.html page on document.ready but it is not working

Comment: Please edit your question and add what you just put into your last comment. Apply proper formatting. Remember that a good question is not made only to *get* help but also to *provide* help to others having similar problems.

Comment: How does it "getSolutionURL"? If it is something related to events on index.jsp, then how will it know what happened in the previous page, unless you use post or get? JS files run when page is loaded each time.

Comment: just for an understanding getSolutionURL is used as the method name.